# Logging Ajax calls to analytics

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I'm currently developing a website and based it on a template I bought, which works fine and to change the main panel content does an ajax call to another page to get the page, then strips out the header. Not a great solution, but it looks great.

But this does mean I'm losing analytics value. So, a user lands on /home, and then clicks the "about us" tab and this loads from /about using some jQuery. Is there a way of recording "/about" in analytics so that it gets added as if the user had landed on /about. Some users may land on /about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to track this kinds of interactions in GA and also you won't lose your pageview metrics. This technique relies on a feature of GA called virtual pageviews. More information [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications#tracking_virtual_pageviews)

Basically what you will do is on the /about page you will call

```
ga('set', 'page', '/about.html');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

That way you will see page metrics as any other static page on your website.